# Is it possible to rewrite the logical OR as material implication

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the question:
Is it possible to rewrite the statement:
$\forall y \exists x:  y=0 \lor xy>0$
using the symbol '$\implies$' instead of '$\lor$'?

I've come up with  $\forall y \neq 0 \exists x \implies xy> 0$.
But I'm not sure this is even a valid expression at all.

Comment: Correct: the [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Formal_properties) $P \to Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot P \lor Q$. Thus, you can rewrite $y=0 \lor xy>0$ as $y \ne 0 \to xy>0$.

Comment: But the formula is wrongly written; it must be ∀y∃x y≠0 ⇒ xy>0. Alternatively, ∀y(y≠0 ⇒ ∃x xy>0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any predicates $P$ and $Q$, the statement $\forall y \exists x:  P \lor Q$ is equivalent to $\forall y \exists x:  \lnot P \implies Q$, by the so-called "or-and-if" identity: $P\to Q\equiv \neg P\lor Q$.

So in your case,
$\forall y \exists x:  y=0 \lor xy>0$
is equivalent to
$\forall y \exists x:  y\neq0 \implies xy>0$.

Alternatively, you could write your original statement as
$\forall y :( y=0 \lor \exists x: xy>0)$,
which is equivalent, for the same reason as above, to
$\forall y :( y\neq0 \implies \exists x: xy>0)$,
which may be easier to parse.